# get to state prop from NavLink

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

I have an object - chat in some component where is defined my `NavLink`. After click on `ChatsElement` - which is a link, my page go to `/friends/${chat._id}` url. Under that url is `MoblieConversation` component, where I want to use chat object which should be passed as `state` via `NavLink`. There is where I read about this idea - [enter link description here](http://ui.dev/react-router-v4-pass-props-to-link)

```
<NavLink
  to={{ pathname: `/friends/${chat._id}`, state: chat }}
  key={chat._id}
>
  <ChatsElement chat={chat} />
</NavLink>
```

.

```
<Route path="/friends/:id" component={MobileConversation} />
```

But I don't know how to get to this `state` prop in component which is under link `/friends/${chat_id}`. I tried something like this, but didn't work :v

```
import React from "react";
import { useParams, RouteComponentProps } from "react-router";
import styles from "./mobileConversation.module.scss";

interface IParams {
  id: string;
}
type SomeComponentProps = RouteComponentProps;


const MobileConversation: React.FC<SomeComponentProps> = ({ state }) => {
  const { id } = useParams<IParams>();
  const chat = location.state;
  return <div>{id}</div>;
};

export default MobileConversation;
```

Comment: Your code does not make sense. From my understanding, you want to pass some state to your ChatsElement? If so, simply import the component that you want to pass state to and send the state down to the ChatsElement component as props. - You also need state to pass state, your code has no state.

Comment: I added also `Route` to better understandig. I have an object - chat in some component where is defined my NavLink. After click on `ChatsElement` - which is a link, my page go to `/friends/${chat._id}` url. Under that url is MoblieConversation component, where I want to use `chat` object which should be passed via NavLink. There is where I read about this idea - https://ui.dev/react-router-v4-pass-props-to-link/

Comment: I hope that I explained it better now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `MobileConversation` is directly rendered by a `Route` component and is receiving [route props](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-props) then you can access the route state via the `location` prop, i.e. `props.location.state.chat`.

```
const MobileConversation: React.FC<SomeComponentProps> = ({
  location,
  state,
}) => {
  const { id } = useParams<IParams>();
  const { chat } = location.state;
  return <div>{id}</div>;
};
```

Since this is a functional component and you are already using react-router-dom hooks, you can use the [useLocation](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/uselocation) hook. I'm not very familiar with typescript at all, so hopefully the interface gets you close to what you need.

```
interface ILocation {
  state: any;
}

const MobileConversation: React.FC<SomeComponentProps> = ({ state }) => {
  const { id } = useParams<IParams>();
  const location = useLocation<ILocation>();
  const { chat } = location.state;
  return <div>{id}</div>;
};
```

Comment: I have one more question. I have an `member` object with `online` status value in this `chat` object. I will change this `online` value sometimes. Should I make a copy of `member` and get this to component state, in some useEffect at the first component render ?

Comment: @poldeeek I would say if you are receiving it into state you are ok though it doesn't hurt to copy in, but when you go to update it via an effect you'll want to apply the same patterns as any state update, shallow copy properties into a new object reference *and then* update the properties on the new object. This is to avoid object/state mutations.